# Do transitive dependencies need to be on the compile-time path?

Tags: java, maven, build

I am using Maven as my build tool for my java application, but this question might be applicable to other build tools.

I declared a dependency on `A.jar` in my pom.xml

`A.jar` also had a pom.xml and declared a dependency on `B.jar`

I used classes from `B.jar` in my code, and maven compiled my code just fine.

I'm confused because I would have expected to have to explicitly declare a dependency on `B.jar` in *my* pom.xml in order to use stuff from it.

Is this normal behavior for other build tools (adding transitive dependencies to the compile time path)?

Why do you *need* transitive dependencies in order to compile?  I understand that they are needed when the code is packaged and/or at runtime.  But I can't seem to think of a case where transitive dependencies are needed for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a dependency if you have an import.

The mvn dependency:analyze can help.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the thought is

...the jar is going to be packaged to be used at runtime ( by the dependency A.jar). So why not let the project have access to them.